# Unexpected Token Error Defining Data in JSX React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, webpack-4

I am trying to use React with D3 in an Electron application, with WebPack 4.

Currently, I am just trying to get a test example building.  I believe I have the integration of the different technologies done - I am able to draw basic hardcoded shapes without issue.

However, several examples define data to pass from the application JSX script but I receive an error when using the sample code.  Based on researching the issue here, I believe to be related to the compilation of JSX.  I have added support for 'react' and 'es2016' but I have not been able to resolve it.

Here is the code in question:

```
export default class App extends Component {

    state = {
        data: [12, 5, 6, 6, 9, 10],
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        id: root
    }

    render() {
       /* ... not listed for brevity ... */
    }
}
```

Here is my 'webpack.config.js':

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {

    watch: true,

    target: 'electron-renderer',

    entry: './app/src/renderer_process.js',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app/build',
        publicPath: 'build/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2016']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: {
                    modules: true
                  }
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                query: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'bundle.css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ],

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx']
    }

}
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
ERROR in ./app/src/App.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:/Projects/MyTestApp/app/src/App.jsx: Unexpected token (21:10)

  19 | export default class App extends Component {
  20 |
> 21 |     state = {
     |           ^
  22 |         data: [12, 5, 6, 6, 9, 10],
  23 |         width: 700,
  24 |         height: 500,
```

What am I missing, or am I looking down the wrong path?

Many Thanks,

BW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your .babelrc file to be able to use this syntax.

try this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2016"],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

and remove this line from your wabpack

```
 options: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2016']
          }
```

or if you don't want to mess with installing babel plugins, just put it in a constructor

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: [12, 5, 6, 6, 9, 10],
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        id: root
    };
  }
```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the quick reply.  I don't have a .babelrc file.  The config is completely defined in the webpack.config.js file.  Is this wrong?

Comment: @BigWinston let me how that go

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer.  In the end, I played around with dependencies all day and couldn't get it to work.  I will put the private member declarations in the constructor for now and try again when I'm more familiar with webpack and babel.